# One computer on network redirected to 127.0.0.2 instead of website, other can access fine

Tags: windows, internet, windows-8.1, redirection, localhost

www.reddit.com is being redirected to 127.0.0.2 on one computer on the network, but the other is fine. I have already checked the hosts file and the website is not listed. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any network monitoring/management software on the network?

Comment: BUCTools router, but it redirects to a specific page showing that it was blocked, not to the computer itself, and another computer on the network can access the website fine.

Comment: what do you mean by "not to the computer itself"? Would it be possible to post a screenshot of this block page?

Comment: all 127.x.x.x are localhosts

Comment: I've seen this behavior on infected machines. Can you run an AV/Malware utility and report your findings? I prefer an rkill/combofix pair.